# how to filter the data based on the input given using angular2

Tags: angular, pipe

[image]

I have an input search field, if i give data inside the search field it must filter the users based on the user name given.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab label="Active">
      <mat-icon for="search">search</mat-icon>
      <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="filter" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Company">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages| messagefilter: filter" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">
          <span>{{message.messages[message.messages.length -1].updated_at  | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
          <img style="width: 40px;" [src]="message.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
          <p style="padding-top: 16px;display: inline;">{{message.from_user_name}}</p>
          <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.messages[message.messages.length -1].text}}</b></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </mat-tab>
```

Pipe.ts:

```
    /* Package filter to write filter functions for Package*/
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'messagefilter',
  pure: false
})

export class MessagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items, filter) {
    console.log(items);
    console.log(filter);
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
  }
  /* Function to apply filter for Messages */
  applyFilter(user, filter): boolean { 
    if (filter && filter != user.from_user_name) { 
        return false;
    }  
    // if the user passes all the filters, show it
    return true; 
  }
}
```

i have pasted the updated code. please let me know where im wrong

Comment: what is issue , you code looks ok

Comment: also provide code where you used pipe

Comment: input field i have used that is the html file

Comment: where you applied `messagefilter ` piple in your html do you have any other code ?? or you need that code

Comment: [(ngModel)]="filter.from_user_name"

Comment: given my answer have look

Comment: sorry sorry, i now pasted my code.. ya il do

Comment: @PranayRana i have pasted image of console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filter logic` seems to be wrong,

Change the logic to,

```
if (filter == user.from_user_name) { 
    return true; 
} else{ 
    return false; 
}
```

**Your Pipe becomes:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'messagefilter',
  pure: false
})

export class MessagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items, filter) {
    console.log(items);
    console.log(filter);
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
  }
  /* Function to apply filter for Messages */
  applyFilter(user, filter): boolean { 
    if (filter == user.from_user_name) { 
        return true; 
    } else{ 
        return false; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular (compared to AngularJs) it's not recommended to use Pipes to filter or change data. One should use them only to format how existing data looks (with some rare exceptions).

You already have the filter value in the model so you can create a different property that will use it and return the filtered list, you already have something like that in the pipe:

```
filteredMessages = items.filter((item) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
```

And then use this in the template:

```
<tr *nfFor = "let d in filteredMessages">
```